# Show a Settings XML in a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, xml, settings, propertygrid

I serialized a Properties.Settings object to a XML string and now I want to deserialize it again in an other application to display it in a PropertyGrid. I have this code but it doesn't work. I use c#. How can I do this?

```
string XMLSettings = webService.AdminGetSettings();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Properties.Settings));
TextReader tr = new StringReader(XMLSettings);
Properties.Settings test = (Properties.Settings)xs.Deserialize(tr);
```

Comment: InvalidOperationException
There was an error reflecting property 'Properties.Settings'

Comment: Can you post the inner exception?